# can BeanUtils.setProperty() set value without setter?

Tags: java, apache-commons-beanutils

I'm currently taking an example from [here](https://github.com/sveluri/ecommerce/blob/master/src/com/ecommerce/dao/ResultSetMapper.java) to map my `ResultSet` to custom `Object`. I've tested `BeanUtils.setProperty()` and it seems like the object would need setters to work. Is there any way to map values like what `Gson` does? I don't want to have public setters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it can't.

As the name implies the BeanUtils deal with [Java Beans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaBeans)

> They are serializable, have a zero-argument constructor, and *allow access to properties using getter and setter methods*.

(Emphasis mine.)

Though the Javadoc of the BeanUtils methods is quite vague clues can also be found in the source code of [`BeanUtilsBean.setProperty()`](https://github.com/apache/commons-beanutils/blob/BEANUTILS_1_9_3/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanUtilsBean.java#L1016) and [`PropertyUtilsBean.setSimpleProperty()`](https://github.com/apache/commons-beanutils/blob/BEANUTILS_1_9_3/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/beanutils/PropertyUtilsBean.java#L2086).

See the [documentation](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/javadocs/v1.9.3/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/package-summary.html#standard.background) too:

> The Java language provides classes like java.beans.Introspector, which can examine a Java class at runtime and identify for you the names of the *property getter and setter methods*, [...]. The APIs in the BeanUtils package are intended to simplify getting and setting bean properties dynamically, [...].

(Emphasis mine.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use @Data annoation from Lombok library in the Entities.

Comment: i don't want public setters. not even the hidden ones